# Getting keyboard size from userInfo in Swift

Tags: swift, uikeyboard

I have been trying to add some code to move my view up when the keyboard appears, however, I am having issues trying to translate the Objective-C examples into Swift. I have made some progress, but I am stuck on one particular line.

These are the two tutorials/questions I have been following:

[How to move content of UIViewController upwards as Keypad appears using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097831/how-to-move-content-of-uiviewcontroller-upwards-as-keypad-appears-using-swift)
http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/move-view-when-keyboard-appears

Here is the code I currently have:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var keyboardSize = notification.userInfo(valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey))
    UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
    let frame = self.budgetEntryView.frame
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - keyboardSize
    self.budgetEntryView.frame = frame
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    //
}
```

At the moment, I am getting an error on this line:

```
var keyboardSize = notification.userInfo(valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey))
```

If someone could let me know what this line of code should be, I should manage to figure out the rest myself.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

There are some problems in your line:

```
var keyboardSize = notification.userInfo(valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey))
```

- `notification.userInfo` returns an *optional* dictionary `[NSObject : AnyObject]?`,
  so it must be unwrapped before accessing its values.
- The Objective-C `NSDictionary` is mapped to a Swift native Dictionary, so you must
  use the dictionary subscript syntax (`dict[key]`) to access the values.
- The value must be cast to `NSValue` so that you can call `CGRectValue` on it.

All this can be achieved with a combination of optional assignment, optional chaining and optional casts:

```
if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
   if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
       // ...
   } else {
       // no UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey entry in userInfo
   }
} else {
   // no userInfo dictionary in notification
}
```

Or in one step:

```
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
    // ...
}
```

**Update for Swift 3.0.1 (Xcode 8.1):**

```
if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
    if let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
        let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
        // ...
    } else {
        // no UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey entry in userInfo
    }
} else {
    // no userInfo dictionary in notification
}
```

Or in one step:

```
if let keyboardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
    // ...
}
```

**Update for Swift 5 (Xcode 11.6):**

```
 guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
              let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
```

I recommend using `keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` since the keyboard changes the initial render height after the first display on older iOS devices.

Comment: @MartinR I am sorry I commented into the wrong post :) sorry

Comment: Hi, I am trying to get the keyboard size with notifications, but I can’t get it to work.  I add the observer  in viewDidload (also tried viewWillAppear)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil) But the method is not called.  I tried it on a real device and the simulator.  Any advice? Thank you very much.

Comment: There is cgRectValue in "one step" answer, but should be CGRectValue

Comment: @krotov The first part of the answer is for Swift 2, the second part for Swift 3. That property was renamed between these releases.

Comment: I think it is better to use UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey instead of UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey for the case when keyboard frame changes (predictive enabled or switch to emoji keyboard for iOS 9 or later)

Comment: instead of "as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue" you can directly use "as? CGRect"

Comment: @andrei: Indeed, that was introduced with Swift 3.0.1 (SE-0139). Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @MartinR this doesn't seem to work for text views, only text fields. Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 18):

For even less code consider looking at [THIS](http://dasdev.de/2014/11/29/adjust-for-the-keyboard-in-ios-using-swift/)

It was really helpful to me.
You just have to include the view constraint in the view controller and using the two observers you added. Then just use the following methods (it is supposed here you move a tableView)

```
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = sender.userInfo {
            if let keyboardHeight = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size.height {
                tableViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
if let userInfo = sender.userInfo {
  if let keyboardHeight = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size.height {
    tableViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in self.view.layoutIfNeeded() })
  }
} }
```

Comment: I ddn't get this answer until I saw it somewhere else, where it became clear to me that tableViewBottomConstraint is an outlet to the Xib. Then it became clear this is the perfect answer! (If you are using auto-layout)

Comment: @JorisvanLiempd Yes, I'm using auto layout. Good it helped you.

Comment: It seems the animation comes free without the animation block. which in this answer does not follow the keyboard curve and duration anyway.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using storyboard, rather than manipulating the view itself, you can take advantage of auto-layout.

(This is a cleaned up version of Nicholas's Answer)

Set up notification center to notify you of the appearance and disappearance of the keyboard:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}
```

And make sure that you remove the observers when you don't need them any more:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)
}
```

Inside storyboard, set the bottom constraint. Create an outlet of that constraint:

[image]

and set the constraint's constant property when the keyboard is shown or hidden:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo! as NSDictionary).objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)?.CGRectValue.size.height else {
        return
    }
    nameOfOutlet.constant = keyboardHeight
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    nameOfOutlet.constant = 0.0
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Now, whenever the keyboard appears or disappears, autolayout will will take care of everything.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 2**

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification:NSNotification) {
        guard let info:[NSObject:AnyObject] = notification.userInfo,
            let keyboardSize:CGSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size else { return }

        let insets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.scrollView.contentInset.top, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)

        self.scrollView.contentInset = insets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
    }
```

**Swift 3**

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification:NSNotification) {
    guard let info:[AnyHashable:Any] = notification.userInfo,
        let keyboardSize:CGSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size else { return }

    let insets:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.scrollView.contentInset.top, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0.0)

    self.scrollView.contentInset = insets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it help me very much!

Answer (score 3):

This helped me : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/Swift_UICatalog_TextViewController_swift.html

```
let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as NSNumber).doubleValue
let keyboardScreenBeginFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as NSValue).CGRectValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one line for your line

```
var keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size
```

Comment: It isn't safe to force unwrap the keyboard frame from that dictionary. Could not be there.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3: UPDATE**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Details

- Xcode Version 11.1 (11A1027), iOS 13, Swift 5

### Solution

```
import UIKit

protocol KeyboardNotificationsDelegate: class {
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification)
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification)
    func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification)
    func keyboardDidHide(notification: NSNotification)
}

extension KeyboardNotificationsDelegate {
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {}
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {}
    func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {}
    func keyboardDidHide(notification: NSNotification) {}
}

class KeyboardNotifications {

    fileprivate var _isEnabled: Bool
    fileprivate var notifications: [KeyboardNotificationsType]
    fileprivate weak var delegate: KeyboardNotificationsDelegate?

    init(notifications: [KeyboardNotificationsType], delegate: KeyboardNotificationsDelegate) {
        _isEnabled = false
        self.notifications = notifications
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    deinit { if isEnabled { isEnabled = false } }
}

// MARK: - enums

extension KeyboardNotifications {

    enum KeyboardNotificationsType {
        case willShow, willHide, didShow, didHide

        var selector: Selector {
            switch self {
                case .willShow: return #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:))
                case .willHide: return #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:))
                case .didShow: return #selector(keyboardDidShow(notification:))
                case .didHide: return #selector(keyboardDidHide(notification:))
            }
        }

        var notificationName: NSNotification.Name {
            switch self {
                case .willShow: return UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification
                case .willHide: return UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification
                case .didShow: return UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification
                case .didHide: return UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - isEnabled

extension KeyboardNotifications {

    private func addObserver(type: KeyboardNotificationsType) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: type.selector, name: type.notificationName, object: nil)
    }

    var isEnabled: Bool {
        set {
            if newValue {
                for notificaton in notifications { addObserver(type: notificaton) }
            } else {
                NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
            }
            _isEnabled = newValue
        }

        get { return _isEnabled }
    }

}

// MARK: - Notification functions

extension KeyboardNotifications {

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        delegate?.keyboardWillShow(notification: notification)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        delegate?.keyboardWillHide(notification: notification)
    }

    @objc func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        delegate?.keyboardDidShow(notification: notification)
    }

    @objc func keyboardDidHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        delegate?.keyboardDidHide(notification: notification)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var keyboardNotifications: KeyboardNotifications! = {
        return KeyboardNotifications(notifications: [.willShow, .willHide, .didShow, .didHide], delegate: self)
    }()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        keyboardNotifications.isEnabled = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        keyboardNotifications.isEnabled = false
    }
}

extension ViewController: KeyboardNotificationsDelegate {

    // If you don't need this func you can remove it
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("keyboardWillShow")
        guard   let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: NSObject],
                let keyboardFrame = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
        print("keyboardFrame: \(keyboardFrame)")
    }

    // If you don't need this func you can remove it
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) { print("keyboardWillHide") }

    // If you don't need this func you can remove it
    func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) { print("keyboardDidShow") }

    // If you don't need this func you can remove it
    func keyboardDidHide(notification: NSNotification) { print("keyboardDidHide") }
}
```

### Full Sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var keyboardNotifications: KeyboardNotifications! = {
        return KeyboardNotifications(notifications: [.willShow, .willHide, .didShow, .didHide], delegate: self)
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 30))
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        view.addSubview(textField)

        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        keyboardNotifications.isEnabled = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        keyboardNotifications.isEnabled = false
    }
}

 extension ViewController: KeyboardNotificationsDelegate {

    // If you don't need this func you can remove it
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("keyboardWillShow")
        guard   let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: NSObject],
                let keyboardFrame = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }
        print("keyboardFrame: \(keyboardFrame)")
    }

    // If you don't need this func you can remove it
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) { print("keyboardWillHide") }

    // If you don't need this func you can remove it
    func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) { print("keyboardDidShow") }

    // If you don't need this func you can remove it
    func keyboardDidHide(notification: NSNotification) { print("keyboardDidHide") }
}
```

### Result

[image]

### Log

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Swift - Keyboard Height From keyboardWillShowNotification

You can grow or shrink a constraint, or any other value, to the size of the keyboard using data from the keyboard Will/did Show/hide Notifications.

### With a Layout Constraint

This minimal code registers for notification that the keyboard will show and updates a constraint based on its size.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var keyboardConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
let keyboardConstraintMargin:CGFloat = 20

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        if let keyboardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
            self.keyboardConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height + self.keyboardConstraintMargin
        }
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        self.keyboardConstraint.constant = self.keyboardConstraintMargin
    }
}
```

### With a ScrollView

In the same way this updates the content inset of a scroll view based on the keyboard's size.

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
    if let keyboardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {
      let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
      self.scrollView.contentInset = insets
      self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
    }
  }
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    self.scrollView.contentInset = insets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

Here's an example of retrieving the keyboard size and using it to animate a view upward.  In my case I am moving a UIView containing my UITextFields upward when a user begins typing so they can complete a form and still see the submit button at the bottom.

I added an outlet to the *bottom space constraint* of the view I wanted to animate and named it named `myViewsBottomSpaceConstraint`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myViewsBottomSpaceConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

I then added the following code to my swift class:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! [String: NSObject] as NSDictionary
    let keyboardFrame = userInfo.value(forKey: UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! CGRect
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.height
    myViewsBottomSpaceConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    myViewsBottomSpaceConstraint.constant = 0.0
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For xamarin, you can use 
c#6

```
private void KeyboardWillChangeFrame(NSNotification notification)
{
        var keyboardSize = notification.UserInfo.ValueForKey(UIKeyboard.FrameEndUserInfoKey) as NSValue;
        if (keyboardSize != null)
        {
            var rect= keyboardSize.CGRectValue;
            //do your stuff here
        }
}
```

c#7

```
  private void KeyboardWillChangeFrame(NSNotification notification)
   {
       if (!(notification.UserInfo.ValueForKey(UIKeyboard.FrameEndUserInfoKey) is NSValue keyboardSize)) return;
       var rect= keyboardSize.CGRectValue;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

in **Swift 4.2** you can use UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey

````swift
guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo , let keyboardFrame:CGRect = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect  else { return  }```
````