# Query Available iOS Disk Space with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storage

I'm trying to get the available iOS device storage using `Swift`.  I found this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25142432/633251)

```
func deviceRemainingFreeSpaceInBytes() -> NSNumber {
    let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let systemAttributes = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath(documentDirectoryPath.last as String, error: nil)
    return systemAttributes[NSFileSystemFreeSize] as NSNumber
}
```

But at compile time this error is given: `[NSObject : AnyObject]? does not have a member named 'subscript'`  I believe this error arises from the issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25451390/633251), namely that `attributesOfFileSystemForPath` returns an optional dictionary ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfFileSystemForPath:error:)).  I understand the problem in a general sense, but because the suggested solution involves a nested case, I don't quite see how to fix the function I'm interested in (it doesn't help that I'm quite new to `Swift`).  Can someone suggest how to make the function work?  NOTE: I'm not sure if the original function was tested by the author or if it worked under an xcode 6 beta, but it doesn't work under the GM as far as I can see.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### iOS 11 Update

The answers given below no longer provide accurate results under iOS 11. There are new volume capacity keys that can be passed to `URL.resourceValues(forKeys:)` that provide values that match what is available in device settings.

- `static let volumeAvailableCapacityKey: URLResourceKey`
  Key for the volume’s available capacity in bytes (read-only).
- `static let volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey: URLResourceKey`
  Key for the volume’s available capacity in bytes for storing important resources (read-only).
- `static let volumeAvailableCapacityForOpportunisticUsageKey: URLResourceKey`
  Key for the volume’s available capacity in bytes for storing nonessential resources (read-only).
- `static let volumeTotalCapacityKey: URLResourceKey`
  Key for the volume’s total capacity in bytes (read-only).

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey/checking_volume_storage_capacity):

> #### Overview
>
> Before you try to store a large amount of data locally, first verify that you have sufficient storage capacity. To get the storage capacity of a volume, you construct a URL (using an instance of URL) that references an object on the volume to be queried, and then query that volume.
>
> #### Decide Which Query Type to Use
>
> The query type to use depends on what's being stored. If you’re storing data based on a user request or resources the app requires to function properly (for example, a video the user is about to watch or resources that are needed for the next level in a game), query against `volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey`. However, if you’re downloading data in a more predictive manner (for example, downloading a newly available episode of a TV series that the user has been watching recently), query against `volumeAvailableCapacityForOpportunisticUsageKey`.
>
> #### Construct a Query
>
> Use this example as a guide to construct your own query:

```swift
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String)
do {
    let values = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey])
    if let capacity = values.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage {
        print("Available capacity for important usage: \(capacity)")
    } else {
        print("Capacity is unavailable")
    }
} catch {
    print("Error retrieving capacity: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

---

### Original Answer

*Optional binding* with `if let` works here as well.

I would suggest that the function returns an optional `Int64`, so that it can return
`nil` to signal a failure:

```
func deviceRemainingFreeSpaceInBytes() -> Int64? {
    let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    if let systemAttributes = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath(documentDirectoryPath.last as String, error: nil) {
        if let freeSize = systemAttributes[NSFileSystemFreeSize] as? NSNumber {
            return freeSize.longLongValue
        }
    }
    // something failed
    return nil
}
```

**Swift 2.1 Update:**

```
func deviceRemainingFreeSpaceInBytes() -> Int64? {
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).last!
    guard
        let systemAttributes = try? NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath(documentDirectory),
        let freeSize = systemAttributes[NSFileSystemFreeSize] as? NSNumber
    else {
        // something failed
        return nil
    }
    return freeSize.longLongValue
}
```

**Swift 3.0 Update:**

```
func deviceRemainingFreeSpaceInBytes() -> Int64? {
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last!
    guard
        let systemAttributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: documentDirectory),
        let freeSize = systemAttributes[.systemFreeSize] as? NSNumber
    else {
        // something failed
        return nil
    }
    return freeSize.int64Value
}
```

Usage:

```
if let bytes = deviceRemainingFreeSpaceInBytes() {
    print("free space: \(bytes)")
} else {
    print("failed")
}
```

Comment: Super, thank you!  I'm going to have to study this to be sure I know how/why it works, and thanks for the 2nd version too.

Comment: Why do these return approx. 200mb (200495104) of free space. While iOS won't allow me to take any pictures, and i can't save a 7mb video to disk?

Comment: Thank's what I observed too. Strange thing there. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: As @LucèBrùlè mentioned the same thing is getting when i run the above code. showing around 215089152 bytes. but  when i check in app storage showing few bytes. any way to find out exact ,as same as showing in app storage settings? thanks in advance

Comment: Hey @SubinKKuriakose i put in a lot of research, but there's actually no really accurate way of getting the remaining free space. I guess it has something to do with iOS starting cleaning up stuff while running low, which actually always changes.

Comment: Does anyone know, is there a way to request iOS to clean the memory immediately? It is a common situation that some space should be available, but actually it is not.

Comment: it doesn't match the memory which is showing in settings, in settings it shows zero kb and through this it shows 49 mbs remaining... i dont understand why

Comment: I edited this answer to give more accurate results on iOS 11.

Comment: @pwc: Thank you!

Comment: this does not return correct values, for example: on my iPhone (128 GB) it returns 119 GB (127933894656 bytes)

Answer (score 64):

Well, according to the above codes:

```
let usedSpace = totalDiskSpaceInBytes - freeDiskSpaceInBytes
```

you might find out that **usedSpace** doesn't equal the value of iPhone setting page. That is because in iOS11, Apple introduces **Total available capacity in bytes for "Important" resources**.

> Total available capacity in bytes for "Important" resources, including
> space expected to be cleared by purging non-essential and cached
> resources. "Important" means something that the user or application
> clearly expects to be present on the local system, but is ultimately
> replaceable. This would include items that the user has explicitly
> requested via the UI, and resources that an application requires in
> order to provide functionality.

> Examples: A video that the user
> has explicitly requested to watch but has not yet finished watching or
> an audio file that the user has requested to download.

> This value
> should not be used in determining if there is room for an
> irreplaceable resource. In the case of irreplaceable resources, always
> attempt to save the resource regardless of available capacity and
> handle failure as gracefully as possible.

In order to get the exact same value as what we see in iPhone setting page, we can get free space by **volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage**

```
if let space = try? URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String).resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey]).volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage {
    return space ?? 0
}
```

You can use the following [UIDevice extension](https://gist.github.com/zhihuitang/6b2205f12925b528128de76aff0cd983):

**Swift4**

```
extension UIDevice {
    func MBFormatter(_ bytes: Int64) -> String {
        let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = ByteCountFormatter.Units.useMB
        formatter.countStyle = ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.decimal
        formatter.includesUnit = false
        return formatter.string(fromByteCount: bytes) as String
    }
    
    //MARK: Get String Value
    var totalDiskSpaceInGB:String {
       return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: totalDiskSpaceInBytes, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.decimal)
    }
    
    var freeDiskSpaceInGB:String {
        return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: freeDiskSpaceInBytes, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.decimal)
    }
    
    var usedDiskSpaceInGB:String {
        return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: usedDiskSpaceInBytes, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.decimal)
    }
    
    var totalDiskSpaceInMB:String {
        return MBFormatter(totalDiskSpaceInBytes)
    }
    
    var freeDiskSpaceInMB:String {
        return MBFormatter(freeDiskSpaceInBytes)
    }
    
    var usedDiskSpaceInMB:String {
        return MBFormatter(usedDiskSpaceInBytes)
    }
    
    //MARK: Get raw value
    var totalDiskSpaceInBytes:Int64 {
        guard let systemAttributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String),
            let space = (systemAttributes[FileAttributeKey.systemSize] as? NSNumber)?.int64Value else { return 0 }
        return space
    }
    
    /*
     Total available capacity in bytes for "Important" resources, including space expected to be cleared by purging non-essential and cached resources. "Important" means something that the user or application clearly expects to be present on the local system, but is ultimately replaceable. This would include items that the user has explicitly requested via the UI, and resources that an application requires in order to provide functionality.
     Examples: A video that the user has explicitly requested to watch but has not yet finished watching or an audio file that the user has requested to download.
     This value should not be used in determining if there is room for an irreplaceable resource. In the case of irreplaceable resources, always attempt to save the resource regardless of available capacity and handle failure as gracefully as possible.
     */
    var freeDiskSpaceInBytes:Int64 {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            if let space = try? URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String).resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey]).volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage {
                return space ?? 0
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        } else {
            if let systemAttributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String),
            let freeSpace = (systemAttributes[FileAttributeKey.systemFreeSize] as? NSNumber)?.int64Value {
                return freeSpace
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
    
    var usedDiskSpaceInBytes:Int64 {
       return totalDiskSpaceInBytes - freeDiskSpaceInBytes
    }

}
```

usage:

```
print("totalDiskSpaceInBytes: \(UIDevice.current.totalDiskSpaceInBytes)")
print("freeDiskSpace: \(UIDevice.current.freeDiskSpaceInBytes)")
print("usedDiskSpace: \(UIDevice.current.usedDiskSpaceInBytes)")
```

[image]

Comment: This should be the top answer in 2018.

Comment: Still the top answer in 2022.

Comment: systemFreeSize] as? Int64 etc., there's no need for NSNumber casting.

Answer (score 21):

I have written a class to get available/used memory using Swift. 
Demo at: https://github.com/thanhcuong1990/swift-disk-status

Upgrade to support Swift 3.

```
import UIKit

class DiskStatus {

    //MARK: Formatter MB only
    class func MBFormatter(_ bytes: Int64) -> String {
        let formatter = ByteCountFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = ByteCountFormatter.Units.useMB
        formatter.countStyle = ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.decimal
        formatter.includesUnit = false
        return formatter.string(fromByteCount: bytes) as String
    }


    //MARK: Get String Value
    class var totalDiskSpace:String {
        get {
            return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: totalDiskSpaceInBytes, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.binary)
        }
    }

    class var freeDiskSpace:String {
        get {
            return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: freeDiskSpaceInBytes, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.binary)
        }
    }

    class var usedDiskSpace:String {
        get {
            return ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: usedDiskSpaceInBytes, countStyle: ByteCountFormatter.CountStyle.binary)
        }
    }


    //MARK: Get raw value
    class var totalDiskSpaceInBytes:Int64 {
        get {
            do {
                let systemAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String)
                let space = (systemAttributes[FileAttributeKey.systemSize] as? NSNumber)?.int64Value
                return space!
            } catch {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }

    class var freeDiskSpaceInBytes:Int64 {
        get {
            do {
                let systemAttributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String)
                let freeSpace = (systemAttributes[FileAttributeKey.systemFreeSize] as? NSNumber)?.int64Value
                return freeSpace!
            } catch {
                return 0
            }
        }
    }

    class var usedDiskSpaceInBytes:Int64 {
        get {
            let usedSpace = totalDiskSpaceInBytes - freeDiskSpaceInBytes
            return usedSpace
        }
    }

}
```

Demo:

[image: get disk space status with Swift]

Comment: Nice!  I like the display aspect.

Comment: It's nice & helped me. Thank you!

Comment: Xcode 7.3: `Use of unresolved identifier 'ByteCountFormatter'`

Comment: unfortunately the value is different the one on iPhone About page

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Martin's answer for **Swift 3.1**, but is converted to an extension of `UIDevice` to make accessing it easier.

```
extension UIDevice {
    var systemSize: Int64? {
        guard let systemAttributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String),
            let totalSize = (systemAttributes[.systemSize] as? NSNumber)?.int64Value else {
                return nil
        }

        return totalSize
    }

    var systemFreeSize: Int64? {
        guard let systemAttributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfFileSystem(forPath: NSHomeDirectory() as String),
            let freeSize = (systemAttributes[.systemFreeSize] as? NSNumber)?.int64Value else {
                return nil
        }

        return freeSize
    }
}
```

To get free space:

```
UIDevice.current.systemFreeSize
```

And to get total space:

```
UIDevice.current.systemSize
```