# Could not cast value of type '_SwiftValue' error

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to fill my arrays with datas in `JSONArray` that i get from server and I'm doing that with this code(swift 3 Xcode 8):

```
 func parseReservationJson(_ anyObject:Array<AnyObject>){
            nodes.removeAll()
            reservations.removeAll()
            for anyObj in anyObject{
                let client_name = (anyObj["client_name"] as? String) ?? ""
                let client_family  =  (anyObj["client_family"] as? String) ?? ""
                let ft_of_time = ((anyObj["ft_of_time"] as AnyObject as! NSString).substring(to: 5) as NSString)
            }
    }
```

But I'm getting this error for the last line of `for` statement :

```
Could not cast value of type '_SwiftValue' (0x112d8a898) to 'NSString' (0x11003eab8).
```

what is wrong?

Comment: What is `_SwiftValue`? You are going to cast the result of `anyObj["ft_of_time"]` to `NSString` and the compiler says you can't. And use the native Swift `substringTo`. I know it's more difficult to get the appropriate index but it's more reliable.

Comment: I wouldn't ask if i knew the answer! i don't have any idea why I'm getting that error for converting `AnyObject` to `NSString` @vadian

Comment: OK, next question: What is the actual type of the result of `anyObj["ft_of_time"]`?

Comment: A string like "10:20:25" @vadian

Comment: I wrote an answer

Comment: I'm getting this in console `Optional(10:30:00)` @Hamish

Comment: @Amir_P Yes, I realised after posting my comment that it'd be an optional. The problem is that Swift has no idea how to bridge optionals to Objective-C, so it falls back on boxing it with `_SwiftValue` – which isn't castable to `NSString`. See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033194/anyobject-not-working-in-xcode8-beta6) for more info about `_SwiftValue`.

Comment: thanks that was the problem and solved @Hamish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error reason is that Swift 3 `AnyObject?` cannot be cast directly to Foundation `NSString`.

You could write

```
let ft_of_time = ((anyObj["ft_of_time"] as! String as NSString).substring(to: 5) as NSString)
```

---

But I recommend to replace the entire line with

```
let ftOfTime = anyObj["ft_of_time"] as! String
let ft_of_time = ftOfTime.substring(to:ftOfTime.index(ftOfTime.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)) as NSString
```

It does the same but it uses native Swift API. Except the final cast to `NSString` (if needed at all) there is no type casting back and forth.

Comment: the code was working with swift 2 but after converting to swift 3 it stopped working

Comment: `NSString` is foundation but `String` isn't? then what is `String`?

Comment: `String` is a native Swift type, a struct with value type semantics (unlike Foundation's `NSString` which is reference type). It's quite similar to `NSString` but has a few different functions. For compatibility `String` can be easily bridged to `NSString`.

Answer (score 2):

The bad point resides here:

```
anyObj["ft_of_time"] as AnyObject
```

(Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39521600/6541007).)

If you are sure `anyObj["ft_of_time"]` is of type `NSString`, simply use `as!`, else you should use Optional binding:

```
if let rawFt_of_time = anyObj["ft_of_time"] as? NSString {
    let ft_of_time = Utils.convert_string(string: rawFt_of_time.substring(to: 5) as NSString)
    //Use ft_of_time here...
}
```

Do not use `as AnyObject` to silence the compiler...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `String` to `NSString` like

```
let swiftString:String = "Swift style string"
let objCString:NSString = NSString(string:swiftString)
```

so first cast your `string` to `nsstring` properly then you can use `methods` of `nsstring`

Answer (score -1):

This problem (Could not cast value of type '_SwiftValue' to 'NSString') can be solved like this too:

```
    let price = "\(String(describing: single_product_dict.value(forKey: "total_price_format") ?? ""))"
    cell.lblPrice.text = price
```